# MySQL Like search for any Japanese character in a string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like, cjk

I'm working on a Japanese website development. I have something like the following database in MySQL:

```
+--------+-------+
| id     | kanji |
+--------+-------+
| 1      |    明 |
| 2      |    令 |
| 3      |    暗 |
| 4      |    週 |
+--------+-------+
```

I need to do a SELECT so when the value "明暗" is searched, rows 1 and 3 are selected. I know REGEXP could do something like that with the pattern [...], but it does not seem to work good with Chinese (or in this case, Japanese) characters. It shows a wider range of results. It seems like LIKE work better with these charset, but I don't know how to do so. Does anyone know how to do this query?

Thanks!

----- EDIT -----

For REGEXP I'm trying the following query:

```
SELECT id, kanji
FROM kanjidic2 
WHERE kanji REGEXP '[明暗]';
```

However, these are some of the results (the query found 3842 matches, where there whould be only 2).

[results for query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ7Dr.png)

Comment: Do you mean this? `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE KANJI IN (N'明','暗');`

Comment: I know spliting search would work (even an OR would do the job), but I can't slipt the string, as it is given from a variable in php from a searching bar.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using? Multibytes characters on REGEXP was introduced at version 8.0 so it won't work properly with the older versions. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html ( Regular expression support )

Comment: @akky I'll transcript the information as I am wuite new into mySQL:
innodb_version: 5.6.39
protocol_version: 10

I guess it is version 10, but when I run REGEXP, the result of the query is way more rows than the two with the two characters in the query :/

Comment: You said in a previous comment that you are unable to split the search string. Why is that? It shouldn't matter whether it's parsed as a PHP variable.

Comment: @Martin The main reason is I don't know how to do so. I think this could turn more into a php question, but I was wondering if there was a way of doing so just with SQL.

Comment: @juan-camilo-orjuela not InnoDB or protocol version. MySQL version must not be 5.x if you want to use Unicode in REGEXP. What does "select VERSION();" return? I suspect your MySQL server version is 5.6 or something.

Comment: @JuanCamiloOrjuela the better way would be to handle it in your PHP script, before sending it to MySQL. However, MySQL do have various methods for splitting strings and get your desired result.